# Solutions on collectible IL emitting on .NET Standard?

Tags: .net-standard, cil, reflection.emit, mono.cecil

I have tried some solutions,

System.Reflection.Emit - `AssemblyBuilder.Save` and some other APIs are missing from .NET Standard, it only supports running but cannot save the dll file. According to the discussion on github, they are unlikely to add supports for this.

Mono.Cecil - the `TargetRuntime` enum has only .NET Framework targets. And I did not find any solution for emitting the dll files that target .NET Standard or .NET Core.

Roslyn - the APIs are all about converting from C# code `string` or `Expression` directly to assemblies rather than from IL codes or some object models like `ILGenerator`.

I just want an alternative for generating dll files from IL, simply like System.Reflection.Emit, on .NET Standard. None of them works fine. Is there any solution?